# Else block of javascript program always executes even If block is true

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

Else block keeps executing even if is true. If I remove else block then program works fine. All I want to do is to check if the user is not in the record then it prints not found.

```js
var students = 
[
 {
  name: "Linda",
  track: "IOS",
  points:' 50'
 },
 {
  name: "Brian",
  track: "Android",
  points: '80'
 },
 {
     name: 'Trish',
     track: 'Rails Development',
     points: '350'
 }
];

   var search = " ";
    var student;
    var message = " ";

 function print ( msg )
 {
  var output = document.getElementById("output");
  output.innerHTML = msg;
 }

 function studentReport( student )
 {
  var report  = "<h2> Student name: " + " " + student.name + "</h2>";
   report += "<p>  Student track: " + " " + student.track+ "</p>";
   report += "<p>  Student points: "+ " " + student.points+ "</p>";
   return report;
 } 

 var button = document.getElementById("search");

  /*search = prompt("Enter a name to search database or type quit to exit");*/
  button.onclick = function( )
 {
  
  search = document.getElementById("txtField").value;
  for( var i = 0; i < students.length; i++ )
  {
   student = students[i];

   if( student.name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase() )
   {
    message = studentReport(student);
    print(message);
   }
   
   else
   {
    message = "<h2> Student not found </h2>";
    print( message);
   }

  }

  
  
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="#">
   <input type="text" name="search" id="txtField"><!--
   --><a href="#" id="search"> Search </a>
  </form>
  

 <div id="output">

 </div>

 </div>
```

By removing else part program search the names and displays the student records. Else part should check if the student is not present in the array then it prints not found.

Comment: Your code updates the exact same HTML element every time it goes through the loop, so you'll only see the message printed for the very last student in the list.

Comment: And therefore "Trish" is found :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `break;` to your `if` statement, so the loop stops evaluating.  Otherwise, only the last result will update the HTML.

Comment: But in this case he will only have one student in the case that two or more students match.

Comment: @Archangel: If they have equal names `student.name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()` - you can't tell them apart anyway ;-) (But in theory you are right, there might be equal names with different scores, and search might be better used with "contains")

Comment: There are two students  with the same name but don't know how to code the program such that it gives user two choices for choosing the right one.

Comment: @knight – Add them to an array in your `if` block, then pass the array to your `studentReport` (which should loop over the length of the array).  Drop the `else` block and only print the Not Found message if the array you generated in your first loop is empty.

Answer (score 1):

try to change,

```
if( student.name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase() )
        {
            message = studentReport(student);
            print(message);
        }
```

to

```
if( student.name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase() )
        {
            message = studentReport(student);
            print(message);
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you break after finding a student, you will find the first match (or display that no student is found). If you want to display all students that are found, I see two approaches, you can either create a list of all students found, or construct an html string which contains all the information. I'll go with creating a list of all found students -- creating a string is very similar.

```
findStudents = function(search) {
    var foundStudents = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < students.length; ++i) {
        if(students[i].name.toLowerCase() === search.toLowerCase()) {
            foundStudents.push(students[i]);
        }
    }
    return foundStudents;
}
```

This will create a list of all found students, from here you can easily render them all, and if the list is empty (i.e. nothing is found), you can display that no student is found.

Your current code always executes students.length times and sets the variable msg, so only the last student matters. If the search string is the same as the last student, the correct string will be found.

Comment: by just adding break to if statement the code works perfectly except with new problem of having more than one student with the same name. Any idea ?

Comment: The above snippet should find all students matching the search string. Don't use break here. This passes through the entire array and finds all matches. From here you can render each one individually.